# Handling Interval with onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So basically I'm making a notification system for a webapp.

The system works with a NotificationProvider component that wraps the whole app:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <NotificationProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home /> } />
        <Route path='/terms' element={<Home /> } />
        <Route path='/legal' element={<Home /> } />
        <Route path='/sign-up' element={<SignUp /> } />
        <Route path='/faq' element={<Questions />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path='/privacy' element={<Privacy />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
      </NotificationProvider>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

The NotificationProvider component just handle the information and map it into another component:

```
const NotificationProvider = (props) => {

    const notifications = [{
        id: v4(),
        type: 'SUCCESS',
        message: 'test'
    }];
  return (
    <div>
        <div className={'notification-wrapper'}>
          {notifications.map(note => {
              return <Notification key={note.id} {...note} />
          })}
          </div>
        {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The notification component just show the props and handle a "progress bar" for the notification changing the width. I'm trying to pause this time bar when the mouse is on top of the notification.

```
const Notifications = (props) => {

    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
    const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = useState(null);
    
    const handleStartTimer = () => {
        console.log('start')
        const id = setInterval(() => {
          setWidth(prev => {
            if (prev < 100) {
              return prev + 0.5;
            }
            clearInterval(id);
            return prev;
          });
        }, 20);
        setIntervalID(id);
      };

    const pauseTimer = () => {
        console.log('pause')
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        handleStartTimer();
    }, [])

  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={pauseTimer} onMouseLeave={handleStartTimer} className={`notification-item ${props.type === 'SUCCESS' ? 'success' : 'error'}`}>
        <p>{props.message}</p>
        <div className={'bar'} style={{width: `${width}%`}}  />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I can see in the console that the function is being called when I enter or Leave the notification with the mouse. However, the progress bar never pause, so I guess I'm doing something wrong with the interval I can't see where.

[This is how the progress bar looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBD0V.png)

Comment: You should check: https://youtu.be/HhpbzPMCKDc?t=3217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what you could do instead : storing the setInterval in a ref, and place the calls and controls of the setIntervall inside of a useEffect so you are sure to have total control over it.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const intvl = useRef(null);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [pause, setPause] = useState(false)

  const inc = () => setCount(prev => prev + 0.5)

  const handleStartTimer = () => setPause(false)

  const handlePauseTimer = () => setPause(true)

  useEffect(()=> {  
    !pause ?
      intvl.current = setInterval(inc, 20)
      : 
      clearInterval(intvl.current)
 
    count === 100 && clearInterval(intvl.current) 

    return () => clearInterval(intvl.current) 
  },[pause, count])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <div 
        onMouseEnter={handleStartTimer} 
        onMouseLeave={handlePauseTimer}
      >
      pause/start
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing it is because your are defining your clearInterval inside of the useEffect.
You can't get access to that id variable wich contains the clearIntervall, from outside of the useEffect. If you want to get access to the intervall, you have to define it first outside of the useEffect scope so to get acess to it, some trick like that.

This is why when you call your pauseTimer function, it doesn't clear the intervall

Comment: You' re right here. I removed the call to handleStartTimer() in the useEffect and now the bar is paused. If I pass the mouse above, the timer start and pause as intended.

But I'm saving in the State the ID right at the end of the handleStartTimer():
```setIntervalID(id);```

Why is still unavailable out of the scope if the state is global?